# Search by keyword is not working properly magento 2

Tags: magento2, search

When i search by full name of product the result in grid of product does not show the product. So is there a problem to fix and how to make search by sku product functionnal any help please and thanks in advance

Comment: where are you trying, it frontend or admin section product catalog grid ?

Comment: of course Backend  how can i make the sku a fullindex text so that when i tab the sku of product it will load the product directly

Comment: In product catalog grid click on  Filter button  then put sku in sku input field and apply filter.

Comment: but he just show me all the product that begin with this sku because i have product that have a common begin of sku

Comment: Can you provide some example search terms?

Comment: for example Piqure 17x22 i  as sku and i also have Piqure 17x22 Brouillon so how to just get Piqure 17x22